# com.segment.analytics.android:analytics, 4.9.4 error when uploading flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, firebase

I have seen others post about this issue but in regards to expo/react. I am getting this error when trying to upload an appbundle built with flutter. I have tried upgrading all of my dependencies with no luck

> Your app <> version code 27 includes SDK com.segment.analytics.android:analytics, 4.9.4 or an SDK that one of your libraries depends on, which collects personal or sensitive data that includes but may not be limited to Advertising ID, Android ID identifiers. Persistent device identifiers may not be linked to other personal and sensitive user data or resettable device identifiers as described in the User Data policy.

Answer (score 0):

The error above just went away. Updating the packages must have fixed the issue, just not after the first try, there may have been some cached versions.